# What are the changes required for migrating Jboss 6 to Jboss 7.1.1

Tags: java, jboss7.x, jboss6.x

I'm using jdk 1.8 also i have tried changing jboss modules with 'jboss-modules-1.1.5.GA' in the root folder. No errors when the server is started but the server is not up and running. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Facing below

JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" starting

Comment: check the documented migration guide: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.1/html/migration_guide/index

Comment: I'd highly suggest not migrating to JBoss AS 7.1 as that is a very old at this point.